# RaspBerry Pi pwmchip0 doesn't always work

Tags: pi-4, hardware, pwm

I'm in a project currently using the RPi's pwmchip0 to implement Hardware PWM. I added the dtoverlay   = pwm-2chan in the cofig.txt. Now when I follow that explanation https://jumpnowtek.com/rpi/Using-the-Raspberry-Pi-Hardware-PWM-timers.html, the PWM doesn't always start. I can't figure why, sometimes the signals get nice and working but sometimes nothing happens at all. Does someone maybe knows what could possibly cause this ? I need to use hardware PWM and not RPi.GPIO's software because of precision.

Thank you

Comment: What does the author of the article say?

Comment: I've written them an e-mail but still no answer.. ^^